Editing OCR text layer
What software can I use to edit the OCR text of an OCRed PDF file?
I have tried gscan2pdf which does have this feature. However, I have two problems with it:

It changes the font size of the OCRed text. Consequently, correctly OCRed text on the right of the page cannot be found any longer, since it falls out of the page range.

It undoes the cropping of the PDF, so that all the pages would need to be recropped.


Is there other software that can be used to edit the OCR layer of a PDF file?

OCRFeeder is a complete Optical Character Recognition and Document Analysis and Recognition program.
Author: Joaquim Rocha
OCRFeeder comes with a graphical user and a command line interfaces.
For help on how to use the command line interface, run the command:
ocrfeeder-cli --help
The graphical interface also features documentation on how to use it.
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/ocrfeeder
